# Recommendations AI: Problem with importing products to catalog. Error: "Long-running operation had neither response nor error set"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-cloud-recommendation

Im trying to import product to Recommendations AI catalog using "googleapis/
python-retail" Python package. But when i do it using ProductServiceAsyncClient an error is returned to me `"google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None Unexpected state: Long-running operation had neither response nor error set."`

In "Recommendations AI -> Data -> Import Activity" i don't have any log.
I have no error either

I tried to get the manually uploaded products using this package and import them again to rule out the wrong format. But it also fails

My example code:

```
async def import_products():
    product_client = ProductServiceAsyncClient()

    product_obj = Product(
        id='product-id',
        categories=["Larry", "Steve", "Eric"],
        title='title',
    )

    product_items = [product_obj]
    
    product_inline_source = ProductInlineSource(
        products = product_items
    )

    product_input_config = ProductInputConfig(
        product_inline_source = product_inline_source
    )

    import_products_request = ImportProductsRequest(
        parent="projects/xxxxxxx/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/default_branch",
        input_config=product_input_config
    )
    
    import_products = await product_client.import_products(
        request=import_products_request,
        timeout=1000
    )

    return import_products

asyncio.run(import_products())
```

Comment: If the issue still persists, please update your question with the exact code and process that you’re trying so that I will be able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your example code with proper authentication and was able to import the products successfully into the Recommendations AI product catalog.

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operation) documentation, it might also be possible that the import operation is still in progress and as a result the ‘done’ parameter of the long-running operation is not set to ‘TRUE’.

Implemented Code:

```
import asyncio
from google.cloud import retail
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud.retail import ProductServiceAsyncClient, Product, ProductInlineSource, ProductInputConfig, ImportProductsRequest

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "path_to_key.json"
PROJECT_NUM = "my-project"

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
 SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

async def import_products():
   product_client = retail.ProductServiceAsyncClient(credentials=credentials)

   product_obj = Product(
       id='product-id',
       categories=["Larry", "SteveS", "Eric"],
       title='title',
   )

   product_items = [product_obj]
  
   product_inline_source = ProductInlineSource(
       products = product_items
   )

   product_input_config = ProductInputConfig(
       product_inline_source = product_inline_source
   )

   import_products_request = ImportProductsRequest(
       parent="projects/<project-id>/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/default_branch",
       input_config=product_input_config
   )
  
   import_products = await product_client.import_products(
       request=import_products_request,
       timeout=1000
   )

   return import_products
asyncio.run(import_products())
```